# what's the purpose of the dependencies array in django migration files

Tags: django

I have a django app with migrations. At one point in the past, I decided to delete a migration because it wasn't necessary, and I assumed it was safe to do that because I just updated the dependency in the next migration to be dependent on the previous migration:

```
migration 1
migration 2 <-- was dependent on 1, but deleted
migration 3 <-- was dependent on 2, but now depends on 1
```

but this was causing weird behavior in django where starting the server kept telling me I have unapplied migrations, and trying to run migrations would attempt to re-run migrations that were already applied. The other weirdness is, when I dropped the db and re-created, and ran migrations, it showed that all migrations ran successfully, but when I checked which migrations actually ran, it only shows 1 to have been applied:

running migrations:

```
  Applying banner.0001_initial... OK
  Applying banner.0003_auto_20180716_1309... OK
  Applying banner.0004_auto_20180716_1520... OK
  Applying banner.0005_auto_20180716_1529... OK
  Applying banner.0006_auto_20180716_2225... OK
  Applying banner.0007_auto_20180717_1939... OK
  Applying banner.0008_auto_20180723_1409... OK
  Applying banner.0009_auto_20180723_1420... OK
  Applying banner.0010_auto_20180723_1423... OK
  Applying banner.0011_auto_20180723_1424... OK
  Applying banner.0012_auto_20180723_1427... OK
  Applying banner.0013_auto_20180822_0057... OK
  Applying banner.0014_auto_20180905_1435... OK
```

checking which ran:

```
# result of running `python manage.py migrate --list`
banner
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0003_auto_20180716_1309
 [ ] 0004_auto_20180716_1520
 [ ] 0005_auto_20180716_1529
 [ ] 0006_auto_20180716_2225
 [ ] 0007_auto_20180717_1939
 [ ] 0008_auto_20180723_1409
 [ ] 0009_auto_20180723_1420
 [ ] 0010_auto_20180723_1423
 [ ] 0011_auto_20180723_1424
 [ ] 0012_auto_20180723_1427
 [ ] 0013_auto_20180822_0057
 [ ] 0014_auto_20180905_1435
```

I'm surprised that django doesn't show an error when the migrations are running, and instead just says 'OK', is this expected behavior? Also, what's the point of having the dependency array if it still relies on the files themselves?

UPDATE:

The migration that was deleted was #2; after the initial migration. It was called: 0002_migration_name.py

FWIW, these were the contents of the migration, which is why it was deleted:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from __future__ import unicode_literals 

from django.db import models, migrations    


class Migration(migrations.Migration):  

    dependencies = [    
        ('banner', '0001_initial'), 
    ]   

    operations = [  
        # migrations.AddField(  
        #     model_name='banner',  
        #     name='name1', 
        #     field=models.IntegerField(default=1), 
        #     preserve_default=True,    
        # ),    
        # migrations.AddField(  
        #     model_name='banner',  
        #     name='name2', 
        #     field=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, verbose_name=b'UTM Value', blank=True), 
        #     preserve_default=True,    
        # ),    
    ]
```

interestingly, adding a new 0002 migration with an empty operations array, and updating dependencies so that 2 is dependent on 1, and 3 is depend on 2, fixes the issue

the way I checked which migrations ran was:

1. first, I ran this command: `python manage.py migrate --list`
2. Then, I checked the django_migrations table in the db, and it only had 1 record for the 'banner' migrations

Comment: What was in the migration you deleted?

Comment: My question was "what was _in_ the migration you deleted", not about its name. It's possible those changes are irrelevant or reversed in a following migration. `makemigrations` looks at the current state of your code and compares it to the result of faux-applying all migrations to date, then generates a migration (if necessary) that's the diff.

Comment: @AKX the operations array was literally fully commented out, so it was a no-op, which is why it was deleted. Interestingly, I added a new 0002 migration file, with an empty operations array, and fixed the dependencies arrays for the relevant migration files, and this issue goes away and all the banners migrations are applied successfully

Comment: @AKX see updated question